# How to deal with Xcode update to recommend settings warning?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Recently, I upgraded to Xcode 6. Anything works well except I got a new warning indicates me to upgrade `iOS Deployment Target` to 8.0. Bellow is a screen shot of the message.

[image: recommend upgrade iOS Deployment Target to 8.0]

However, I don't want to upgrade deployment target because I want to support any device that has OS version 7.0 and above.

How to ignore this warning? Or perhaps `iOS Deployment Target` setting has nothing to do with the lowest OS version that my app can support?

Comment: upgrading target vil nt do any harm to ur old target versions, as these vil also b available alongside

Comment: upvote because of same question and solution !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is a bit of confusion here, there is a difference between the Base SDK setting and the  Deployment Target. Deployment target determines which versions of iOS you support, the SDK version simply determines which version of the SDK you are using to write your code. As long as you don't use any code which requires iOS 8 (Or if you want to use it check that it is available: [Checking For Class Availability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/using/using.html)). So to fix this, you should click Perform Changes. You will still be able to run your app on iOS 7 :)